# How did Iowa go from being a "blue" to "red" state?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, religion, iowa

In [1988,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1988_United_States_presidential_election) Democrat Michael Dukakis won Iowa 55-45, a margin second only to Rhode Island, despite losing the general election 46-54. As late as 2008 and 2012, Barrack Obama won the state. Yet Iowa went for Trump by 8-9 percentage point margins. in 2016 and 2020.

This has been attributed to the evangelical vote. But in 1988, Business Week attributed Dukakis' strength to " a church-based peace movement." (Reagan, and by implication Bush, was considered a "warmonger.")

What caused the flip of the state? Are today's "evangelicals" a modern version of the earlier "peaceniks?" Are they opposite sides of the same coin? Or are they two different phenomena altogether?

Source: Wikipedia articles for respective years.

Comment: [Iowa was historically a "red" state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_presidential_elections_in_Iowa), with an impressive 14-election Republican streak from 1856 to 1908, broken by Woodrow Wilson in 1912.  So maybe you should be treating 1988-2012 (when the Democrats won 6 out of 7 elections in Iowa) as an exception to a long-term "red" trend, instead of as your baseline.

Comment: @dan04: I wouldn't go back 100 years (maybe 50), because of all the "flipping"  that has taken place during that time. For instance, most of the formerly Confederate states were Democratic until the 1960s, and Republican since. On the other hand, New York, now a solidly blue state, was Republican (other than during FDR and Grover Cleveland, both former governors), until JFK in 1960.

Comment: "Church-based"and "evangelical" do not necessarily mean the same thing. A [growing fraction of people](https://relevantmagazine.com/faith/church/new-data-suggests-over-40-percent-of-self-identified-evangelicals-attend-church-once-a-year-or-less/) who identify as evangelical do not go to church. Among the general population (as opposed to religious scholars) it's becoming more of a political identity and not so much a religious belief system.

Comment: @TomAu: True, elections 100 years ago have little relevance to US politics today, but even if you start in 1968, Republicans won 8/14 (57%) of the presidential elections in Iowa.

Answer (score 21):

*The New York Times* had a recent article on pretty much this exact question "Why Iowa Turned So Red When Nearby States Went Blue" ([2024-01-08](https://www.nytimes.com/2024/01/08/us/politics/iowa-republicans-red.html)).

These were the reasons they gave:

> Deindustrialization of rural reaches and the Mississippi River regions ...

> hollowing out of institutions, from civic organizations to small-town newspapers ...

> an issue that once would have been handled through discussions at church or the Rotary Club instead became infected with national politics ... New multicolored lighting installed last summer to illuminate the town’s carillon bell tower prompted an angry debate over L.G.B.T.Q. rights, leaving much of the town soured on identity politics that they largely blamed on the national left.

(My interpretation of the last paragraph: Thanks to cable TV, the internet, and then social media, issues that once would not have been widely seen as being tied to some national ideological debate now are and so further add to polarization.)

> Another issue: Brain drain. The movement of young college graduates out of Iowa and the Dakotas to the metropolises of Chicago and Minneapolis-St. Paul made a mark on the politics of all five states. ...
>
> Iowa loses 34.2 percent of its college graduates, worse than 40 of the 50 states, just below North Dakota, which loses 31.6 percent. Illinois, by contrast, gains 20 percent more college graduates than it produces. Minnesota has about 8 percent more than it produces.

Self-sorting (those who lean Democrat tend to move away):

> Iowa ... now has a government almost wholly under Republican control, which has enacted boldly conservative policies that ban almost all abortions and transition care for minors, publicly fund vouchers for private schools and pull books describing sexual acts from school libraries. ...
>
> Meantime on the east bank of the Mississippi, in Illinois, high-capacity semiautomatic rifles have been banned, the right to an abortion has been enshrined in law and recreational marijuana is legal. Upriver in Minnesota, pot is legal, unauthorized immigrants are getting driver’s licenses, and voting access for felons and teens is expanding.
>
> Such policy dichotomies are influencing the decisions of younger Iowans ...
>
> Chased by the shifting politics, ... at least one of her children now plans to move his family across the border to Minnesota.

The bigger puzzle might instead be why Iowa didn't turn "red" earlier. On this:

> The politics of rural voters in the Upper Midwest may simply be catching up to other rural regions that turned conservative earlier ... Southern rural white voters turned sharply to the right in the 1960s and 1970s as Black southerners gained power with the civil rights movement and attendant legislation ...
>
> But rural voters in the Upper Midwest, where few Black people lived, held on to a more diverse politics for decades longer. North Dakota, with its state bank, state grain mill and state grain elevator, has retained vestiges of a socialist past, when progressive politicians railed against rapacious businessmen from the Twin Cities. ...
>
> Until relatively recently, there was a Midwestern rural white voter who was distinct from a southern rural white voter ... There was a real progressive tradition in the Midwest uncoopted by Jim Crow and racial issues.

Comment: Yet another factor is the decline of the family farm. The rural parts of Iowa have suffered greatly from the shift from 160 acre farms to huge factory farms. Much of the labor has been automated, and what's left is largely seasonal, with those seasonal workers being mostly immigrants, legal and illegal.

Comment: I doubt people self-select because they care so much about voting rights for felons or semi-auto rifle access. It's just that there's more office jobs in other states, so that's where college educated people are moving to. If Chicago was a hardcore Republican city people would still be moving there for work.

Comment: It seems to me that we are just gullible on the whole.    I have republican friends that are convinced we are one administration away from jack-booted thugs breaking in our doors to take our precious guns.

Comment: @JonathanReez: *I doubt people self-select because they care so much* This is just one of many factors in deciding where to live. Nobody (neither I nor NYT) claims that "voting rights for felons or semi-auto rifle access" is the sole criterion in deciding where to live. For many, this could just be something that makes them 2% less likely to live in Iowa. And if many were already on the fence on whether to live in Iowa or say Minnesota, this 2% nudge could cause many of them to choose Minnesota instead of Iowa.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat It's already happened, so yeah.

Comment: @JonathanReez: Well, maybe *you* wouldn't self-select on such a basis, but a highly-politically-opinionated felon (who has gotten out of prison and thus can choose where to live) or a gun collector just might.  Plus there are other issues that affect larger numbers of people.

Comment: @dan04 my point was that all of these factors are likely to be negligible compared to jobs/money, so they might as well not be mentioned.

Comment: @JonathanReez, "voting rights for felons" might not be a common reason to self-select, but "access to abortion" very much is.

Comment: @Mark in practice no - a small percent of women ever need one and a much smaller one can’t afford travel to a neighboring state where it’s legal.

Comment: @JonathanReez Seeing as 49% of women (source: NYT)) who get abortions are under the poverty line and the majority already live in blue states, I don't think it's justifiable to claim that a "much smaller percentage" of women cannot afford to travel to another state. Also, the NYTimes cites a source putting the estimated percent of women that receive abortions at some point in their life at near 25%. Adjusting for women who can't afford to travel, you'd expect a higher poverty rate (>50%) ).

Comment: I'd say that "access to legal abortion" is much more about "what kind of place do I want to live in" than "Do I personally need one?". I am a man, I will *never* need an abortion, but if they're made illegal where I live, I'm leaving, because that is not the kind of society I want to contribute anything to.

Comment: Funny, @JasonGoemaat, I thought the gullibility was on the part of my democratic friends who think that the government should be in control of everything and that boys can be girls or girls can be boys. :shrug: If you're going to attempt to offend, remember, the other side of the coin thinks the same about you.

Comment: @FreeMan Sorry if I offended you.    But talking about "girls can be boys and boys can be girls"?   Is that really an issue in your life, or does the media just have you worried about it for no reason?    None of their propaganda seems to match reality in any way I've seen.  I've had a trans friend and it offends me that people would do anything but treat them with respect.  And the other side never seems to think about how others feel, like the parents of the 1 in 5000 children born with ambiguous genetailia.   The right would rather bury their heads in the sand and pretend they don't exist.

Comment: @FreeMan And champion laws they think will prevent men from going into women's restrooms, a problem I've never heard of, when in reality it would force a post-op trans man with a beard and penis to use the women's restroom.

Comment: It has indeed impacted my kids lives. I feel very sorry for those who are so confused by the world that they can't even figure out one of the most simple, basic truths. The left media claiming that "men" can get pregnant by... I don't know what the heck logic they use to claim that just shows how confused supposedly intelligent people can be. I'm not burying my head in the sand, but I refuse to be forced to accept a lie.

Comment: "The left media claiming that "men" can get pregnant by" where is that?